# Warning #224: Cannot determine machine load balance - Using KMP_DYNAMIC_MODE=thread limit

Tags: openmp

Hi I got thi error on a application = Cyclone Register
OMP: Warning #224: Cannot determine machine load balance - Using KMP_DYNAMIC_MODE=thread limit

Its this issue solvable by user or it need correction in actual code of the application  ?

App fall back form multithread to single thread work, so hard limitation.
Tested on i9 and DualXeon v1, same issue

Comment: Which compiler? (Looks like either Intel or LLVM, but we don't know until you tell us...) Which operating system? (Also, Google may be your friend...  https://www.google.com/search?q=OMP%3A+Warning+%23224%3A+Cannot+determine+machine+load+balance

Comment: Solved  today with help of support, but this can be a solution for others. 
app running under Windows 10 x64, unknown  complier or etc. 

Open the Start Search, type in “env”, and choose “Edit the system environment variables”:
- Click the “Environment Variables…” button.

It need to be added to Windows as a variable 

Variable name = KMP_DYNAMIC_MODE
Variable Value = thread_limit 

- Set the environment variables as needed. The New button adds an additional variable. 
- Dismiss all of the dialogs by choosing “OK”. Your changes are saved!

Comment: you should add this as an answer, not a comment, that will make it easier for others to find!

Answer (score 0):

Solved today with help of support, but this can be a solution for others. app running under Windows 10 x64, unknown complier or etc.

Open the Start Search, type in “env”, and choose “Edit the system environment variables”: - Click the “Environment Variables…” button.
It need to be added to Windows as a variable
Variable name = KMP_DYNAMIC_MODE
Variable Value = thread_limit

Set the environment variables as needed. The New button adds an additional variable. - Dismiss all of the dialogs by choosing “OK”. Your changes are saved!